# GIT submodule fatal: cannot describe

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am trying to add a git submodule to my project, but git keep telling me 
$ git submodule
fatal: cannot describe 'dd650e8bb4762a8a7f69a6412b4765c9bb108778'

What means "fatal: cannot describe" and how can i avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly bug in Git (please send description of how it does occur, and the git version to git mailing list), but you can avoid this `git describe` error by creating **annotated tag** pointing somewhere to the commit before adding submodule (with `git tag -s` or `git tag -a`).  For example to some released version.

Answer (score 1):

git describe will throw an error 'cannot describe' if it cannot find an annotated tag and you do not use the --tags switch. See man git-describe and man git-tag for more info on this.